# How to get SQL column name as value on X axis with Devexpress

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I have sql as below:

```
create table Test (City1 int,City2 int,City3 int,City4 int )
insert into Test (City1,City2,City3,City4) values (1250,1450,1350,1243)
```

Then when I get value from SQL server by Query:

```
select City1,City2, City3, City4
from Test
```

Everything is OK. But I want to build chart (Devexpress) using SQL column name as value on X axis.
The result is as below

[image]

I have read Devexpress doc but don't see any information of this problem.
Pls give me your advise

Comment: Have you tried opening a ticket in the DevExpress support center? That is the quickest way to get a correct answer, as they answer most questions within 24 hours.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I had the answer for myself. I found answer in the DevExpress support center